# When to solve limits using sequences

Tags: limits

Like the title says when do we solve a limit using sequences? For example consider $\lim_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac {1}{x}\right) $ here we can use either sequences or boundedness of $\sin $ function. But now consider
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $x$ is rational} \\ 1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational.} \end  {cases}
$$. Then find $f (x)_{\lim {x \to 0}} $
Here we can  use only sequences.  How  one can  be sure that solving a particular limit by sequences would be the most efficient way?

Comment: What limit are you looking for in the second case?

Answer (score 2):

In general, "using sequences" is **never** "the most efficient way" because in order to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= L$ "using sequences" we would have to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)= L$ for *every* sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to a$.

Comment: Exactly.I want to know the cases where they are THE most useful.

Comment: If you can prove by "imprecise" methods that the limit must _exist_, sometimes it can be useful to pick a particular sequence to find what it _is_.

Comment: And I said "**never**"!

Comment: For example, in algorithm analysis, it's not too uncommon that we're looking for $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and it is simple to show that $f$ is increasing and upward bounded (so the limit exists), but it is difficult to work with the exact expression for $f(x)$ -- but comparatively easy to consider for example $f(1), f(2), f(4), \ldots, f(2^n), \ldots$.